# Pester - Code Coverage output to XML file is not working

Tags: pester

```
Invoke-Pester .\CoverageTest.Tests.ps1 -CodeCoverage .\CoverageTest.ps1 -PassThru -OutputFile out.xml
```

Using the above script, I am trying to export the code coverage output to out.xml
but it is not getting exported

Answer (score 0):

Currently I believe the `-OutputFile` switch doesn't write code coverage results to the file, rather it only writes the test results.

However as you've used the `-PassThru` switch, the output object does get a `.codecoverage` property with the code coverage results, so you could indepdently write this to a file. E.g:

```
(Invoke-Pester .\CoverageTest.Tests.ps1 -CodeCoverage .\CoverageTest.ps1 -PassThru -OutputFile out.xml).CodeCoverage | Export-CliXML .\codecov.xml
```

However beware that this wouldn't be in any officially supported format for this type of output.

There is an open feature request asking for Pester to support official code coverage output files here: https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/212

I suggest you watch that issue to see when the feature becomes available.